# Show testng report on slack

Tags: jenkins, slack

I want to show the test result on a slack channel, my jenkins job uses testNG.

I integrated jenkins in Slack, with the slack notifier (i didn't use webhook) but it only show minimal informations

`Job Name- #3 Unstable after 4 mn 3 s (Open)`

What I want is show at least how much successfull and failed tests, if i can parse the testng.xml and show it in slack it would be even better

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project -> Configure -> Post Build Actions -> Advanced

**Select**

- Include Test Summary
- Include Failed Tests

Apply and Save.

[Jenkins Post Build Actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0uoG.png)